# access environment variables of drone in drone plugins

Tags: drone.io

I am completely new to drone CI/CD. I am facing issue on passing environment variables to drone plugin. What i did upto now is

- I deployed drone docker image drone/drone:0.7 in one of my server (my.drone.com) (both server and agent working. bitbucket is integrated successfully) I followed this article: [configre drone on ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-drone-on-ubuntu-16-04) for setup.
- I activated one of my repo for CI/CD in drone admin app
- I added `.drone.yml` file to project
- I did setup automatic image build in `cloud.docker.com` app. Now i want to deploy that image to my other cloud server (`my.app.com`). So,  I added applebody/drone-ssh to drone.yml to access that server
- For this plugin to deploy to my server, it needs to access my server (`my.app.com`) through ssh.
- I can login to `my.app.com` from `my.drone.com` server
- But i dont know how plugin can access my.app.com, I tried to pass my `my.drone.com` **private ssh key** to plugin through environment varibles. But didn't workout. my drone's server and agent env file and `.drone.yml` as follows:

**.drone.yml**

`pipeline:
      ssh:
        image: appleboy/drone-ssh
        host: my.app.com
        user: root
        key: $PLUGIN_SSH_KEY
        script:
          - ls
          - cd apps
          - docker pull drprasad/todo-app
          - docker rm -f todo
          - docker run -p 8080:8080 -d --name 'todo' drprasad/todo-app
       notify:
         image: plugins/slack
         webhook: https://hooks.slack.com/services/token
         channel: test
         username: drone-is-flying`

**agent env file**

```
DRONE_SECRET=my_drone_secret_key
DRONE_SERVER=ws://drone-server:8000/ws/broker
PLUGIN_SSH_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAzMW5gU9I071UdnBDANbvuprd+1QwBEXWUq0gvi44ECUDZhzL
...............................................................
...............................................................
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

**server env**

```
DRONE_SECRET=my_drone_secret_key
DRONE_HOST=my.drone.com:8082
DRONE_OPEN=true
DRONE_BITBUCKET=true
DRONE_BITBUCKET_CLIENT=my_bitbucket_client_token
DRONE_BITBUCKET_SECRET=my_bitbucket_secret_key
PLUGIN_SSH_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAzMW5gU9I071UdnBDANbvuprd+1QwBEXWUq0gvi44ECUDZhzL
...............................................................
...............................................................
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

How can pass `PLUGIN_SSH_KEY` variable (either from agent or server env file) to drone plugin ?? so that it can access my `my.app.com` server

Even I dont know my approach is correct or not. Please correct me if my approach is wrong.

Sorry for my bad english. **Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported syntax. The `key` value in your example is a Go string literal and therefore cannot evaluate a bash expression.

```
key: $PLUGIN_SSH_KEY
```

If you want to pass sensitive parameters (such as keys) to your build you can do so using the drone secret store [1]. You can upload secrets using the command line utility or in the user interface.

You can then pass those secrets to the plugin. Please see the official documentation [1] for a more in-depth explanation. Here is a brief example of how the syntax should look:

```
pipeline:
  image: appleboy/drone-ssh
  host: my.app.com
  user: root
  secrets: [ SSH_KEY ]
```

Note that the plugin expects the secret to be named SSH_KEY. The official documentation [1] describes what to do if the secret has a different name.

Further reading:

[1] http://docs.drone.io/manage-secrets/ 
[2] [Drone CI does not see secret variables when using drone-email plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312429/drone-ci-does-not-see-secret-variables-when-using-drone-email-plugin)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I thought of asking this question to you but could not found you. But magically i got answer from you. I got one more problem now. i updated to drone/drone:0.8. I am getting "DRONE_HOST is not properly configured" error with DRONE_HOST=`http://host_ip`

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally made it work. Anyway i can't buy you a beer. But I will contribute to drone by writing some blog posts ;-)